# How to Compare a TFVC label with the latest source code using Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, tfvc

I'm trying to compare the changes between a label and the latest source, and take the difference files for my deployment. is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean TFVC label?

Comment: Yes, it is TFVC label.  @ShaykiAbramczyk

Answer (score 0):

You can get the label items and version with Rest API, and get also the latest source changeset, then compare them.

Example to a small PowerShell script: (add a PowerShell task in your pipeline)

```
$azureDevopsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}"
$user = ""
$pat = "YOUR-PAT-HERE"  
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get Label Id:
$myLabel = "test"
$url = "$azureDevopsUrl/{project}/_apis/tfvc/labels?api-version=4.0"
$labels = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json).value
$label = $labels.Where({ $_.name -eq $myLabel })

#Get Label Details:
$labelUrl = "$azureDevopsUrl/_apis/tfvc/labels/$($label.id)/items?api-version=4.0"
$labelDetails = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $labelUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json).value

#Get Changeset Details:
$latestSourceChangeset = $env:Build_SourceVersion
$changeSetUrl = "$azureDevopsUrl/_apis/tfvc/changesets/$latestSourceVersion/changes?api-version=4.0"
$cahngeset = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $changeSetUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json).value

# Now compare the versions and get the files you want
```

There is a special variable to get the latest source: `$(Build.SourceVersion)`, so I used it in the script for the `{changeset-id}`, if you run the script not in pipeline replace it specific changeset id.

References to the Rest API: [Labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/labels/list), [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/labels/get%20label%20items) and [Changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes).